# Regular expression for Url rewriting php

Tags: php, regex, apache, url, wamp

I'm using URL rewriting with Wamp but I don't find the correct regex for my needs.

I'd like to transform http://localhost/site_artisans/site_artisans/peintre-annecy.php in http://localhost/site_artisans/site_artisanspeintre-annecy.php (remove the slash between site_artisans/site_artisans and whatever is after).

I thought of :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .*site_artisans/site_artisans/.* site_artisans/site_artisans [L]
```

(Unknown number of characters before and after and slash removed).

But this doesn't work.

Comment: Can you tell us exactly how you want the URL to look? It's not very obvious in your question.

Comment: I want the url http://localhost/site_artisans/site_artisans/peintre-annecy.php to be transformed inhttp://localhost/site_artisans/site_artisanspeintre-annecy.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .*site_artisans/site_artisans/(.*) site_artisans/site_artisans$1 [L]
```

I tested it on http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/ and I believe the result is what you want.

Comment: @Bruno this rule is exactly what you need. And there is an error in my rule

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .*site_artisans/(site_artisans/.*) site_artisans/$1 [L]
```

Comment: And read this section in manual http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

Comment: Do you use RewriteBase directive in your .htaccess file?

Comment: Yes the page is inside a folder and I've put the file .htaccess there too.

Comment: Try this `RewriteBase /` before my or @Vache rule